# How do I identify why my login hangs for 20 seconds at startup?

Tags: debian, login

I've done something (I can't remember what) and now when I log in, just after entering my details, I see the background with my mouse cursor and nothing happening. Then, after about 20 seconds (presumably a timeout) the hard drive keeps loading and I get my desktop.

I tried install `bootchart2`:

`apt-get install bootchart2 pybootchartgui`

I followed their instructions [here](https://github.com/mmeeks/bootchart) and added the following line to `/etc/default/grub`:

`initcall_debug printk.time=y quiet init=/sbin/bootchartd ...`

when I run update-grub I get the following error message:

`/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 12: /etc/default/grub: initcall_debug: not found`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31818/what-to-do-when-a-linux-desktop-freezes

Comment: You can also use `strace` to connect to various processes during login to see what's the hang up: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-strace-command-examples.html

Comment: @slm I wouldn't know where to start with `strace`. How do I find out what's happening at login? What do I run it against?

Comment: @slm I should add that the computer doesn't actually freeze (I can still move the mouse around), there's just no icons and no hard drive activity.

Comment: Right I know it wasn't freezing, but these methods were still appropriate.

Comment: So how do I kill or trace a process when I don't know what it is?

Comment: yes, that works.

Comment: I'm currently using a usb wifi dongle for internet but also have an ethernet connection that is on by default when I start the PC, but doesn't provide internet (I disabled it and connect to wifi). Running `nethogs` results in this: `ioctl failed while establishing local IP for selected device eth0. You may specify the device on the command line.`

Comment: See my A. The comments are too complicated to give details.

Comment: Bootchart is the right tool to diagnose what happens before the login prompt, but it won't help you. Which application are you logging in in: the text console or a display manager, and if the latter which one? What desktop environment or window manager do you start? Do you get the same effect in another one?

Comment: I'm using a new debian wheezy install, so Gnome. It's in the display manager (it's all GUIish if that's what you're asking). I've tried both Gnome and Gnome classic with the same effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of issue can be tricky to debug. For starters it's helpful to isolate it to either a network or HDD access issue.

This is done by eliminating potential causes until you're left with the culprit.

#### Background

Before we get started we'll be making use of several applications that you may need to install. I'm not going to detail how to do this, I'm assuming you know how to install applications and will do so when required to perform a particular step.

Also we'll be making use of the system's console. To access it do the following: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. You can use a similar keyboard combo to switch back to your primary display where your graphical desktop is. That would be this key combo: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

#### Networking

Using the app `nethogs` is a good place to start. I like to use it since it will show you the applications that are trying to access the network. Perhaps one of these applications is causing the hanging.

Before we can use `nethogs` we need to determine which network interface is being used by our system. Here are the ones I have on my laptop:

```
$ ip -o link show | cut -d" " -f2
lo:
em1:
wlp3s0:
virbr0:
virbr0-nic:
vboxnet0:
```

I know from experience that my wireless is `wplp3s0`. The ethernet is `em1`. Let's start with WiFi.

```
$ sudo nethogs wlp3s0
```

Resulting in this type of output:

```
NetHogs version 0.8.0

  PID USER     PROGRAM                      DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
979   saml     ../bin/google-chrome-stable  wlp3s0     1.943       2.547 KB/sec
2376  saml     /usr/bin/pidgin              wlp3s0     0.000       0.000 KB/sec
21789 saml     ssh                          wlp3s0     0.000       0.000 KB/sec
9618  saml     ssh                          wlp3s0     0.000       0.000 KB/sec
10267 saml     ssh                          wlp3s0     0.000       0.000 KB/sec
?     root     unknown TCP                             0.000       0.000 KB/sec

  TOTAL                                                1.943       2.547 KB/sec
```

Once we've isolated the issue to a few PIDs that appear to be lopsided in having a lot of `SENT` data without any receiving data, we'll need to dive in deeper and use `strace` to try and see what aspect of this network access is getting hung up. To accomplish this you can use `strace` like so:

```
$ strace -s 2000 -o somepid.log -p <PID>
```

Where `<PID>` is one of the process IDs identified from `nethogs`.

#### Disk I/O

If we've determined that the issue isn't with our network, the next place to explore would be looking to see if a process is having issues accessing the HDD and getting blocked in some fashion.

This can be trickier to debug but you'll likely make use of tools such as `lsof`, `strace`, and `fatrace` to further refine your search.

#### Anything else?

One place where you can fairly quickly determine if something is suspect is to disable any applications from starting up when you log in. To do this under GNOME you can launch this dialog: `gnome-session-properties`.

[image: ss of dialog]

Within this dialog I'd attempt to disable everything or applications you think are suspect and start doing reboots to see if the issue goes away.

Comment: Ok, when I run that first command I get `lo`, `eth0`, and `wlan0`. `nethogs lo` produces only a single entry: `PID ?, USER root, PROGRAM unknown TCP, SENT 0.000, RECEIVED 0.000`. running `nethogs eth0` results in a large list (this time I didn't disabled the ethernet adaptor). Most of them have no PID and USER as `root`, then a bunch of numbers under `PROGRAM`. One has a PID of 5215 with USER as `armanschwarz` (my username). The program for this one is `..m --password-store=detect` (presumably this is just a partial?)

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz - wlan0 is your wifi. Yes the output is partial.

Comment: Yes, running `nethogs wlan0` produces a mostly empty list, although things seem to come and go. Like with eth0 I have one with my username and that partial program name, and then one with a bunch of numbers as the name.

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz - yes it's showing things as they come and go. We're looking for things that stay on the list and don't go away. Culprits also have a lot of send w/ no receiving. These would be programs that are trying to get a resource that isn't acknowledging them.

Comment: I tried creating a new user account and that account didn't have any problems. Since it's a new install I think I'm going to just nuke my current account and go from there. Thanks for the assistance though I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you could add a brief comment on how I/O could be `strace`d I think that might be helpful for others coming here. I'll mark your response as the answer as I think it's useful.

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz - I've added some additional updates, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, slm and @ArmanSchwarz. You guys just helped me keep my laptop wifi from hanging on a remembered old network at boot.