# How to recover a failed KDE4 desktop without deleting the entire ~/.kde4 directory?

Tags: linux, display-settings, kde4, display-manager

This is a tale of two 64-bit *Mageia 5* GNU/Linux systems equipped with 6xx/7xx *nVidia* video cards.  Each is configured with a *KDE4* desktop (*task-kde4-minimal-4.14.3-2.mga5*), and use a proprietary driver supplied by the distribution (*nvidia-current-kernel-desktop-latest-352.79-10.mga5.nonfree*).  The proprietary driver is required because *nouveau* is inadequate for some applications.  One system seems to work just fine, but another has a most annoying quirk that I don't see happening on the other system:

```
If a particular application is closed, when it shuts down, the desktop
immediately goes to a black screen such that the monitor says the
signal is out of range.
```

A reboot does not fix the problem.  The graphical login (*kdm-4.11.16-5.mga5*) works just fine, but as soon as one logs into a user account with a *KDE* desktop, the problem recurs.

The solutions posted for [What to do when a linux desktop freezes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31818/what-to-do-when-a-linux-desktop-freezes) were considered by do not appear to be effective.

Reconfiguring *xorg* has no impact other than to change how *kdm* configured the display.  *KDE* overrides whatever configuration is set up at the *xorg* level.

After the fault, I have not found any keys including `Ctrl-Alt-Backspace` that can recover some control of the graphical desktop, but I can switch to a console with `Ctrl-Alt-F2`, and I can attempt recovery.

Edit:  Actually, `Ctrt-Alt-Backspace` does work, it just takes either patience or multiple attempts.

After the fault, I can get into a *failsafe* graphical desktop that is a really minimal environment.  It works fine.

After much gnashing of teeth, I found that stopping the desktop manager and deleting the `~/kde4` folder recovers system behavior:

```
# service dm stop
# rm -rf /home/user/.kde4
# service dm start
```

This is a horrible workaround, not to mention that it requires elevated privileges to run.

By the way, the "particular application" is *MineCraft 1.8.9* running under java (*jre1.8.0_91*), but this question is not about why it does that or how to prevent it.  Rather, it is about how one debugs *KDE4* breakage of this nature however it may have happened.

Is there a *KDE-specific* command-line utility that might be off assistance in a scenario like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No elevated permissions are required, and reboot is unnecessary.

- Kill KDE with `Ctrl-Alt-Backspace`.
- Use `Ctrl-Alt-F2` (or another Function key as needed) to get a console.
- Log on as the user that triggered the problem.
- For safety, backup `~/.kde4/share/apps/kscreen/????????????????????????????????`
- Delete `~/.kde4/share/apps/kscreen/????????????????????????????????`

In this specific instance, given the details in the question, the actual file name ws `cc3277aaebc0a310157f935da894a119`, but the file name changes when the .kde4 folder structure is rebuilt.

How did I arrive at this conclusion?  First, I triggered the desktop failure, killed the *KDE* with `Ctrl-Alt-Backspace`, renamed the broken copy of `~/.kde`, restarted *KDE*, then diff'd the good directory with a broken one:

```
$ diff -qr .kde4 kde4.broke
Files .kde4/share/apps/activitymanager/activityranking/database and kde4.broke/share/apps/activitymanager/activityranking/database differ
Files .kde4/share/apps/kconf_update/log/update.log and kde4.broke/share/apps/kconf_update/log/update.log differ
Files .kde4/share/apps/kscreen/cc3277aaebc0a310157f935da894a119 and kde4.broke/share/apps/kscreen/cc3277aaebc0a310157f935da894a119 differ
Files .kde4/share/apps/kwallet/kdewallet.kwl and kde4.broke/share/apps/kwallet/kdewallet.kwl differ
Files .kde4/share/apps/kwallet/kdewallet.salt and kde4.broke/share/apps/kwallet/kdewallet.salt differ
Files .kde4/share/apps/nepomuk/repository/main/data/virtuosobackend/soprano-virtuoso.db and kde4.broke/share/apps/nepomuk/repository/main/data/virtuosobackend/soprano-virtuoso.db differ
Files .kde4/share/apps/nepomuk/repository/main/data/virtuosobackend/soprano-virtuoso-temp.db and kde4.broke/share/apps/nepomuk/repository/main/data/virtuosobackend/soprano-virtuoso-temp.db differ
Files .kde4/share/config/activitymanagerrc and kde4.broke/share/config/activitymanagerrc differ
Files .kde4/share/config/gtkrc and kde4.broke/share/config/gtkrc differ
Files .kde4/share/config/gtkrc-2.0 and kde4.broke/share/config/gtkrc-2.0 differ
Files .kde4/share/config/kdebugrc and kde4.broke/share/config/kdebugrc differ
Files .kde4/share/config/kdeglobals and kde4.broke/share/config/kdeglobals differ
Files .kde4/share/config/kglobalshortcutsrc and kde4.broke/share/config/kglobalshortcutsrc differ
Files .kde4/share/config/khotkeysrc and kde4.broke/share/config/khotkeysrc differ
Files .kde4/share/config/klipperrc and kde4.broke/share/config/klipperrc differ
Files .kde4/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc and kde4.broke/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc differ
```

Differences in only one file seemed certain to be related:

```
$ diff -u .kde4/share/apps/kscreen/cc3277aaebc0a310157f935da894a119 kde4.broke/share/apps/kscreen/cc3277aaebc0a310157f935da894a119
--- .kde4/share/apps/kscreen/cc3277aaebc0a310157f935da894a119   2016-07-04 02:47:56.312121742 -0500
+++ kde4.broke/share/apps/kscreen/cc3277aaebc0a310157f935da894a119      2016-07-02 23:51:04.725895881 -0500
@@ -1 +1 @@
-[ { "enabled" : true, "id" : "39a867a4a7600077629a3c27c6fa77bf", "metadata" : { "fullname" : "xrandr-hp L2335-CNP509Z1GW", "name" : "DVI-I-1" }, "mode" : { "refresh" : 59.9502, "size" : { "height" : 1200, "width" : 1920 } }, "pos" : { "x" : 0, "y" : 0 }, "primary" : true, "rotation" : 1 } ]
\ No newline at end of file
+[ { "enabled" : true, "id" : "39a867a4a7600077629a3c27c6fa77bf", "metadata" : { "fullname" : "xrandr-hp L2335-CNP509Z1GW", "name" : "DVI-I-1" }, "mode" : { "refresh" : 59.8846, "size" : { "height" : 1200, "width" : 1920 } }, "pos" : { "x" : 0, "y" : 0 }, "primary" : true, "rotation" : 1 } ]
\ No newline at end of file
```

Notice the difference seems small and innocuous:  59.9502 vs. 59.8846

Most of other file differences result from a creation date and show no functional difference, or are related to application environment rather than the desktop manager.  One mentioned the "Desktop", but the difference was only in GUID - hardly likely to be directly related to the problem.

To test my hypothesis, I saved a good copy of `.kde4/share/apps/kscreen/cc3277aaebc0a310157f935da894a119`, triggered the desktop failure, and instead of deleting the file, I copied the known good file over the one that was changed after the system failed.  *KDE* recovered.

Next, since most people won't have a good copy of the file on hand, I decided to try deleting it instead of "fixing" it.  Deleting the file also recovered the desktop.