# My computer hangs when I "share screens". How do I start diagnosing it?

Tags: ubuntu, troubleshooting, hang

I've just updated to the latest version (22.04.1 LTS) of Linux through the official updater and my computer is very unstable when sharing screens.

I've been having this issue in OBS, Chrome and Discord.

When I share screens, everything works fine for anywhere between 30mins and a few hours before the system will ultimately hang (no stop code or screen; the GUI just freezes in time and goes unresponsive; mouse doesn't move).

The only way to recover is to either force reboot it (hold the power button) or [REISUB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33891/539122)

What are my next steps to fix or figure out what went on?

Some unrelated information but may be useful:

- OBS is using "Pipewire"
- My system complains of an ACPI BIOS Error `AE_ALREADY_EXISTS`

Comment: reboot, check `sudo journalctl` at the time of freeze. There must be something. AE_ALREADY_EXISTS has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in graphically to gnome using the gear icon at the graphical login, then choose Xorg instead of the default, Wayland.  Numerous issues I was having were corrected with that one change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).