What does alt + PrtSc+ REISB do?
I remember hearing this as a safe way to reboot a frozen system but never looked into what it actually does. What does this command do?

Well answered at https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power

Also the converse question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33891/70524

It is  not a safe way. It just terminates stuff in an undefined order. Don't do it.
